# Pandas: how to select rows based on two conditions in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table and I am trying to select the 'col1' and 'col2' pairs that , at some point in the dataframe, appear with the value 'D' and 'E' in column 'C'.

```
col1    col2    C   val
aaa rte_1   D   58
aaa rte_2   E   47
bbb rte_3   D   2
aaa rte_4   E   35
aaa rte_5   E   95
ttt rte_6   E   84
aaa rte_1   D   57
ddd rte_2   C   36
aaa rte_3   C   13
aaa rte_4   C   28
aaa rte_5   E   3
```

In other words, the result should be

```
col1    col2    C   val
aaa rte_1   D   58
aaa rte_5   E   95
aaa rte_1   D   57
aaa rte_5   E   3
```

I have tried something like this but I get an empty dataframe so it is obviously wrong.

```
d = {'col1' : ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'ttt', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'], 'col2' : ['rte_1', 'rte_2', 'rte_3', 'rte_4', 'rte_5', 'rte_6, 'rte_1', 'rte_2', 'rte_3', 'rte_4', 'rte_5'], 'C' : ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'E'], 'val' : ['58', '47', '2', '35', '95', '84', '57', '36', '13', '28', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)    
df2=df.loc[(df.C =='D')&(df.C =='E')]['A', 'B']
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: When I say that I want to select values that have both "E" and "D", I mean that I want to select the rows that have the same 'col1' and 'col2' pairs and have a "D" and then, at some point in the dataframe, they occur again and have a "E" (or viceversa, "E" first and "D" later).
I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Do you mean ALL col C values for the group have to be either D or E?

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have included the desired output in the question. Column C should have 'D' and 'E'. I will edit the question to make it more clear as I think that some may have understood this.

Comment: The pair `aaa, rte_1` is in your expected output, but only has a `D` value followed by a `D` value, so it doesn't have any `E` values, which contradicts what you are saying `"Column C should have 'D' and 'E'."` My answer gives you the expected output. Can you please confirm if that is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it sounds like you may be trying to do is see if ALL values in a group are only 'B' or 'E'. At the same time, your expected output has also excluded rows that meet that condition but only have one member of the group. You can groupby the "pair" columns you have mentioned and use list comprehension to check if all values are either `D` or `E` with `all([True... )`. I have also included an additional piece of logic `and len(x) > 1`, since your output excludes groups with only one row. This creates a boolean series `s` of `True` or `False` if the condition is met, which you can use to filter directly on the dataframe, and get the "expected output".

```
s = df.merge(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['C'].apply(lambda x: all([True if y in ['D', 'E'] 
                                                                    and len(x) > 1 
                                                                    else False for y in x ]))
             .reset_index(),
             how='left', on=['col1', 'col2']).iloc[:,-1]
df[s]
Out[1]: 
   col1   col2  C  val
0   aaa  rte_1  D   58
4   aaa  rte_5  E   95
6   aaa  rte_1  D   57
10  aaa  rte_5  E    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for search to give true when the column C is both D and E at the same time which is not there. I think you meant OR and for that the operator is "|".
Little change to your code.

```py
d = {'col1' : ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'ttt', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'],
     'col2' : ['rte_1', 'rte_2', 'rte_3', 'rte_4', 'rte_5', 'rte_6', 'rte_1', 'rte_2', 'rte_3', 'rte_4', 'rte_5'],
        'C' : ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'E'],
      'val' : ['58', '47', '2', '35', '95', '84', '57', '36', '13', '28', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2=df[((df.C =='D')|(df.C =='E'))]
print(df2)
```

It gives this output for the data you gave.

```py
   col1   col2  C val
0   aaa  rte_1  D  58
1   aaa  rte_2  E  47
2   bbb  rte_3  D   2
3   aaa  rte_4  E  35
4   aaa  rte_5  E  95
5   ttt  rte_6  E  84
6   aaa  rte_1  D  57
10  aaa  rte_5  E   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the `isin` method, which can be handy when you have a lot of conditions. You can use it like this:

```
df[df.C.isin(['D', 'E'])]
```

to select rows and all columns, and this way to to get only the two columns you need:

```
df[df.C.isin(['D', 'E']), ['col1', 'col2']]
```